# admob says "Server replied that no ads are available"

Tags: android, admob

i have added the admob test in my app as the pdf instructions were directing and everything works nice(in emulator and in my device).In order to stop the test mode and upload my new apk at the market i have to erase the test code from my .java file,right?i have tried it and i uploaded my .apk file in my device (from mass storage)but i cant see any admob...what is my wrong ?

TEST CODE:

```
 AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] { 
                   AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR,"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",});

             AdView adView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
             adView.requestFreshAd();
```

i checked my LogCAT view:

```
01-20 14:13:38.938: INFO/AdMobSDK(19582): No fill.  Server replied that no ads are available (373ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You yourself answered the question

> 01-20 14:13:38.938:
>   INFO/AdMobSDK(19582): No fill.  Server
>   replied that no ads are available
>   (373ms)

Everything is alright. Server has nothing to send you, when it will, you will see the ads.

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable test mode from your `AdMob` account manually. So just login to your `AdMob` Account and go to settings of that application and there you can find a option like this:

[image]

Comment: i have tried this and nothing new happens,logcat has the same "msg"..will i see any difference if i upload it to the market?

Comment: Yes sometimes server doesnt sends any Ad but I believe the server will reply when the number of requests will be increased.

Comment: and the way i get the payment is about the number of requests?

Comment: No when it request for Ads and if server reply an Ad then it will be displayed in AdView this is an **impression** and if a user click on that Ad that will be a **Hit count** so you will get only for a hit.

Answer (score 1):

I observed same results. Just be patient :)
BTW. You don't have to remove `AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR,"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",});`. It affects only your device.

Comment: yes. Better move adView.requestFreshAd(); to Activity::onResume(). Ad will be refreshed. Also, your app could get response from AdMob that there is no ads.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the ad has enough space around it, aka its container should be atleast 320dp wide. I discussed this at length here:
http://cupcake-and-beyond.blogspot.com/2011/05/why-is-my-admob-ad-not-showing-up.html

(I also show a neat trick with the new ad sizes)