# Can't see admob on real android device

Tags: android, admob

I have app in the android market
I add to this app admob ,I can see the advertisement in the test mode.
so I upload a upgrade version to the market.
after that I download the app to my device but I dont see there nothing.
On the website of admob I can see 635 Requests but no money 0.0$
So what is the reason that the advertisement don't show up?

Thanks
Beno

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746949/admob-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admob doesn't serve ads for all requests. In the administration of admob you should be able to find something they call impressions. That is the number of ads actually viewed. You should also find something they call "fillrate". That is the ratio between impressions and requests.

Admob says it might take a while before the system is warmed up before starting to actually return impressions for requests. And you will not see that you make any money unless people press the ads.

So be a little patient and the ads will probably show up.

Best regards
Roland